# WCF Reference Sheet

Tags: wcf

Can i get WCF Cheat Sheet or (Ref Card) any where?

Comment: MSDN has pretty much everything you could ever possible want as far as getting started. I'd check out their resources and articles.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't find any specific crib cards around when I looked a few months back, but the following post by Farooq Kaiser was useful for me!!

http://www.fairnet.com/post/2009/09/14/The-ABC-of-WCF.aspx

I also found Kirk Evans blog entry had some useful links when I started learning about WCF (its a little old but might be a good starting point)

http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2008/04/23/what-you-need-to-know-wcf-wcf-ado-net-syncservices-and-clickonce.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is one recent refcard from Dzone

http://refcardz.dzone.com/

You would need to register though

hope this helps

Comment: Here is the actual link - 
http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-windows-0

Answer (score 0):

Details about Bindings are presented in tabular form here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx